# Sort a list in Python, ignore blanks and case

Tags: python, list, sorting, whitespace, case-insensitive

I have a list (of dictionary keys), which I need to sort. This is my list:

```
listToBeSorted = ["Right  Coronary Artery 2", "Right Coronary Artery 1", "RIght Coronary Artery 3"]
```

Obviously, the order in which I'd like to have these items sorted would be:

```
["Right Coronary Artery 1", "Right  Coronary Artery 2", "RIght Coronary Artery 3"]
```

So I need to find a way to sort, ignoring the double blanks in the first item, and the uppercase "I" in the last item.

I tried the following sorting mechanisms:

1. Plain sorting

   ```
   sortedList = sorted(listToBeSorted)
   ```

   will produce:

   ```
   ['RIght Coronary Artery 3',
    'Right  Coronary Artery 2',
    'Right Coronary Artery 1']
   ```
2. Sorting, ignoring case:

   ```
   sortedList = sorted(listToBeSorted, key=str.casefold)
   ```

   will produce:

   ```
   ['Right  Coronary Artery 2',
    'Right Coronary Artery 1',
    'RIght Coronary Artery 3']
   ```
3. Sorting, eliminating all blanks

   ```
   sortedList = sorted(listToBeSorted, key=lambda x: ''.join(x.split()))
   ```

   will produce:

   ```
   ['RIght Coronary Artery 3',
    'Right Coronary Artery 1',
    'Right  Coronary Artery 2']
   ```

I cannot change the entries themselves, as I need them to access the items in a dictionary later.

I eventually converted the list entries into a tuple, added an uppercase version without blanks, and sorted the list by the 2nd element of the tuple:

```
sortedListWithTwin = []
    
# Add an uppercase "twin" without whitespaces
for item in listToBeSorted:
  sortString = (item.upper()).replace(" ","")
  sortedListWithTwin.append((item, sortString))
       
# Sort list by the new "twin"
sortedListWithTwin.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
    
# Remove the twin
sortedList = []
for item in sortedListWithTwin:
  sortedList.append(item[0])
```

This will produce the desired order:

```
['Right Coronary Artery 1',
 'Right  Coronary Artery 2',
 'RIght Coronary Artery 3']
```

However, this solution seems very cumbersome and inefficient. What would be a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

sort using `lambda`

```py
sortedList = sorted(listToBeSorted, key=lambda x: x.casefold().replace(" ", ""))
print(sortedList)
```

If you don't want to use `replace` for some reason. You could even use regex.
`re.sub()` function will replace all the whitespaces characters with an empty string. `\s+` matches one or more consecutive whitespaces. Maintaining `casefold()` function to ignore case.

```py
import re

sortedList = sorted(listToBeSorted, key=lambda x: re.sub(r"\s+", "", x.casefold()))
print(sortedList)
```

Output:

```
['Right Coronary Artery 1', 
'Right Coronary Artery 2', 
'RIght Coronary Artery 3']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an alternative method, using PyICU (a Python wrapper for icu4c). ICU has quite a powerful and flexible Collator class to allow tailored sorting.

I will include two methods:

1. Create a collator instance for the locale you wish to use, and set the collators attributes.
2. Create a collator instance using a BCP 47 langauge tag with appropriate U extension settings.

For the question solution, I would activate numeric collation, set collation strength to secondary (case distinctions are tertiary, so setting to secondary will give us a caseless sort). Set alternate handling to shifted, this will address the whitespace issue in the question.

**Setting attributes on collator**

```
import icu
listToBeSorted = ["Right  Coronary Artery 2", "Right Coronary Artery 1", "RIght Coronary Artery 3"]
collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale.getRoot())
collator.setAttribute(icu.UCollAttribute.NUMERIC_COLLATION, icu.UCollAttributeValue.ON)
collator.setStrength(icu.UCollAttributeValue.SECONDARY)
collator.setAttribute(icu.UCollAttribute.ALTERNATE_HANDLING, icu.UCollAttributeValue.SHIFTED)
sorted(listToBeSorted, key=collator.getSortKey)
```

**Creating locale from BCP-47 language tag**

```
import icu
listToBeSorted = ["Right  Coronary Artery 2", "Right Coronary Artery 1", "RIght Coronary Artery 3"]
lang = "en-AU-u-kn-true-ka-shifted-kv-space-ks-level2"
loc = icu.Locale.forLanguageTag(lang)
collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(loc)
sorted(listToBeSorted, key=collator2.getSortKey)
```

Both will result in `['Right Coronary Artery 1', 'Right  Coronary Artery 2', 'RIght Coronary Artery 3']`

In the BCP-47 version, I have restricted the alternative handling shift to just whitespace. Alternatively, punctuation, symbols and currency symbols could have been included.

Answer (score -1):

```
sortedList = sorted(listToBeSorted, key=lambda x: x.upper().replace(" ", ""))
print(sortedList)

print(sortedList)
#['Right Coronary Artery 1', 'Right  Coronary Artery 2', 'RIght Coronary Artery 3']
```

Comment: I understand that this would sort the list by the number at the end of the string? This would solve the problem in this particular example, but not a list like this:

['RIght Coronary Artery 3',
 'Right  Coronary Artery 2',
 'Right Coronary Artery 1',
 'Left Coronary Artery 1']

Comment: 'Right Coronary Artery 10'

Comment: Same as @Jamiu except that you use *lower()* rather than the superior *casefold()*

Comment: @Andy I changed it to upper()

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.